# finding onsets (and offsets) of number sequence

Tags: string, matlab

given the following cell array:

```
strings = {'str1', 'str2', 'str2', 'str1', 'str2', 'str2', 'str1', 'str1', 'str2'};
```

I want to find the onsets and offsets (first occurrence and last occurrence) of a particular value. For example, the following are the onsets and offsets for 'str1':

```
onset_str1 = [1, 4, 7, ];
offset_str1 = [1, 4, 8, ];
```

And here are the on- and offsets for 'str2':

```
onset_str2 = [2, 5, 9];
offset_str2 = [3, 6, 9];
```

Currently I do something like this:

```
[blub, ia, ic] = unique(strings, 'first');
all_str1 = find(ic == 1); %  1     4     7     8
all_str2 = find(ic == 2); %  2     3     5     6     9
```

Using `all_str1` and `all_str2` I would then look for consecutive values (using `diff` for example) and determine that way the on and offsets. However this kind of implementation feels 'hackish' to me.

What other ways are there to extract the on and offsets in my sequence efficiently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[blub, ia, ic] = unique(strings, 'first');
```

ok, but next up, just use logicals and [find](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/techdoc/ref/find.html) to find the rising/falling edges:

```
N = numel(blub); % number of unique strings found
str_onsets=cell(N,1);
str_offsets=cell(N,1);
for ii=1:N
    x=ic==ii;
    str_onsets{ii} = find([true ~x(1:end-1)] & x);
    str_offsets{ii}= find(x & [~x(2:end) true]);
end
```

or [strfind](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/techdoc/ref/strfind.html) if that's more clear to understand to you:

```
N = numel(blub); % number of unique strings found
str_onsets=cell(N,1);
str_offsets=cell(N,1);
for ii=1:N
    x=ic==ii;
    str_onsets{ii} = strfind([0 x],[0 1]);
    str_offsets{ii}= strfind([x 0],[1 0]);
end
```

Comment: could you explain the `[true ~x(1:end-1)]` part? I don't see what's happening there :)

Comment: finding where in `x` there is a transition from 0 to 1, originally it was `[0 x(1:end-1)]==false & x==true` (which is the same). You can't just use `x(1:end-1)==false & x(2:end)==true)` because then you'd miss the case where `x(1)=true` which is also an onset.